# Scanning a QR code into a browser text input?

Tags: camera, web-browser

I have a bit of an edge use-case of QR codes. I would like to be able to scan a QR code via a phones camera and have that value pasted into a browser text input.

Is this possible given any current apps or API's?

Comment: So you would not just want a URL, but pre-fill some form element as well when the user scans the code?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible if you let's say generate a QR-code that leads to

http://www.yourdomain.com/yourpage.php?inputtext=1234

When the user scans the QR-code he will be sent to http://www.yourdomain.com/yourpage.php and then your page takes the value of inputtext which is 1234 and puts in the input field of your choice.